# Can we use heterogeneous lookup comparator to perform a "partial-match" search on STL associative containers?

Tags: c++, stl, c++14

So I was looking at support for heterogeneous lookup in STL's associative containers (since C++14) and got a bit confused about what we can do and what we shouldn't.
The following snippet

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

struct partial_compare : std::less<>
{
    //"full" key_type comparison done by std::less
    using less<>::operator();

    //"sequence-partitioning" comparison: only check pair's first member
    bool operator ()(std::pair<int, int> const &lhs, int rhs) const
    {
        return lhs.first < rhs;
    }

    bool operator ()(int lhs, std::pair<int, int> const &rhs) const
    {
        return lhs < rhs.first;
    }
};

int main()
{
    //Using std::set's lookup
    {
        std::cout << "std::set's equal_range:\n";
        std::set <std::pair<int, int>, partial_compare> s{{1,0},{1,1},{1,2},{1,3},{2,0}};

        auto r = s.equal_range (1);

        for (auto it = r.first; it != r.second; ++it)
        {
            std::cout << it->first << ", " << it->second << '\n';
        }

        std::cout << "std::set's lower_bound + iteration on equivalent keys:\n";
        auto lb = s.lower_bound(1);

        while (lb != std::end(s) && !s.key_comp()(lb->first, 1) && !s.key_comp()(1, lb->first))
        {
            std::cout << lb->first << ", " << lb->second << '\n';
            ++lb;
        }
    }

    //Using algorithms on std::set
    {
        std::cout << "std::equal_range\n";
        std::set <std::pair<int, int>> s{{1,0},{1,1},{1,2},{1,3},{2,0}};

        auto r = std::equal_range (std::begin(s), std::end(s), 1, partial_compare{});
        for (auto it = r.first; it != r.second; ++it)
        {
            std::cout << it->first << ", " << it->second << '\n';
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Produces the following output when compiled with clang-5/libc++:

```
std::set's equal_range:
1, 1
std::set's lower_bound + iteration on equivalent keys:
1, 0
1, 1
1, 2
1, 3
std::equal_range
1, 0
1, 1
1, 2
1, 3
```

And the following when compiled with gcc-7.1.0:

```
std::set's equal_range:
1, 0
1, 1
1, 2
1, 3
std::set's lower_bound + iteration on equivalent keys:
1, 0
1, 1
1, 2
1, 3
std::equal_range
1, 0
1, 1
1, 2
1, 3
```

By reading the initial [N3465](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3465.pdf) proposal, I think that what I'm doing here should be fine and conceptually identical to what's in the proposal's initial example: a "partial-match" during lookup, relying on "the notion of sequence partitioning".
Now, if I'm understanding correctly, what actually ended up in the standard is [N3657](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3657.htm), but that doesn't seem to change the concept as it "just" focuses on ensuring heterogeneous lookup member templates are only made available when the provided comparator "is_transparent".
So, I can't really understand why using std::set's `equal_range` member template in clang/libc++ doesn't produce the same results of gcc's or the equivalent "`lower_bound` + scan". 
Am I missing something and using heterogeneous lookup in this way is actually violating the standard (and then clang is right and the difference between `equal_range` and `lower_bound` + scan might be due to UB), or is clang/libc++ wrong?

EDIT: After reading the now accepted answer, I was able to find the relevant [bug report](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=30959) for libc++.
There's also a specific question about the difference in behavior of `equal_range` template members between libc++ and libstdc++ [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40504836/different-behaviour-of-equal-range-member-function-templates-of-associative-orde) on SO that I didn't find while doing my search.
Not sure if this should be deleted or closed, as the one I've linked doesn't have an accepted answer.

Comment: Iterating to `upper_bound` would be much cleaner.

Comment: @o11c true, but since in doubt about what clang is doing, I preferred to use a completely "manual" approach so as to reduce the possibility of being bitten by the same problem that might affect equal_range.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug in libc++: its [equal_range implementation](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/__tree) (at r315179) immediately returns both iterators upon finding an "equal" element even with heterogeneous comparison.